# Enviar ID desde jQuery a una pagina para hacer una CONSULTA

Tags: php, jquery, sql, ajax, formularios

intento explicar, ya que es algo que no había hecho nunca:

- Intento: al abrir un modal, saco un "id" (el del cliente)
- Ahora, intento enviar ese "id" a la misma página que había realizado la acción, pongo el código hasta aquí:

> ```
> $(document).on('click', '.editarCliente', function () {
>
> var id = $(this).attr("id");
> console.log(id);
>
> $.ajax({
>   type: 'POST',
>   url: 'php/editar_cliente.php',
>   data: {'id': id}
> })
> .done(function(listas_rep){
>   $('#resultEditCliente').html(listas_rep)
> })
> .fail(function(err){
>   console.log(err);
>   alert(err);
> })
>
> $(document).on('click', '#cerrarEditarCliente', function () {
>   $('#editarCliente').hide();
> });
>
> });
> ```

¿Para que utilizo esto?
Porque intento, ahora en la página de clientes: crear la siguiente consulta:

```
<?php  

require_once 'php/conexion.php';

function editarCliente() {

    $idcliente = $_POST['id'];

    $mysqli = getConn();

    $query = "SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE id_cliente = $idcliente";
    $result = $mysqli->query($query);

    $ec = '<form id="form_edit_cliente" method="POST">
            <table id="table" width="100%" class="table table-hover table-mc-light-blue">';

    while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
        $ec .= '<h2>Editar cliente #'.$row[id_cliente].'</h2>
                <h3>Datos Personales</h3>

                <input id="idc" type="hidden" value="'.$row[id_cliente].'">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="campoP">Nombre</td>
                        <td class="td"><input id="nombre" type="text" value="'.$row[nombre].'"></td>
                        <td class="td barcode" style="text-align:center" colspan="6" rowspan="2"></td>
                        <td class="campoP">Fecha Registro:</td>
                        <td class="td">' .$row[fecha_registro]. '</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="campoP">Apellidos</td>
                        <td class="td"><input id="apellidos" type="text" value="'.$row[apellidos].'"></td>
                        <td class="td" colspan="5"></td>
                        <td class="td"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="campoP">Telefono</td>
                        <td class="td"><input id="telefono" type="text" value="'.$row[telefono].'"></td>
                        <td class="td" colspan="5"></td>
                        <td class="td"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="campoP">Email</td>
                        <td class="td"><input id="email" type="text" value="'.$row[email].'"></td>
                        <td class="td" colspan="5"></td>
                        <td class="td"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <h3>Datos Comerciales</h3>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="campoP" style="width: 10%">Nombre Comercial</td>
                        <td class="td" style="width: 25%"><input id="ncomercial" type="text" value="'.$row[ncomercial].'"></td>
                        <td class="td" colspan="5"></td>
                        <td class="campoP" style="width: 10%">Nombre Fiscal</td>
                        <td class="td" style="width: 25%"><input id="nfiscal" type="text" value="'.$row[nfiscal].'"></td>
                        <td class="campoP">NIF/CIF</td>
                        <td class="td"><input id="cif" type="text" value="'.$row[cif].'"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="campoP">Direccion</td>
                        <td class="td"><input id="direccion" type="text" value="'.$row[direccion].'"></td>
                        <td class="td" colspan="5"></td>
                        <td class="campoP">Ciudad</td>
                        <td class="td"><input id="ciudad" type="text" value="'.$row[ciudad].'"></td>
                        <td class="campoP">CP</td>
                        <td class="td"><input id="cp" type="text" value="'.$row[cp].'"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>';
    }

    $ec .= '</table>
            <br><br>
            <center><input type="submit" id="submit" value="Editar Cliente"></center>
            </form>';

    return $ec;
}

echo editarCliente();
?>
```

Me devuelve esto por consola:

```
jquery.min.js:4 POST http://localhost:8888/seoagency/php/editar_cliente.php 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Al hacer esto, deja de funcionar todo.

¿Alguien se le ocurre como poder ayudarme?
Gracias.

Comment: Tienes que chequear: `if (isset($idc)) {`

Comment: Vale, acabo de hacer ese `if`antes de la consulta, y no me muestra nada, con lo que no se porque no está recibiendo esa ìd`

Comment: Cómo deja de funcionar? Se traba? Te manda error? Que error te manda? No te regresa nada el back... Le faltan muchos detalles del problema a tu ticket hermano. Lo que estas haciendo es muy fácil, pero necesito saber que está pasando (Hasta imagenes sirven)

Comment: El problema, es que estoy mandando en la `url`del Ajax, el enlace a la página que tiene todo el html y demás, por lo que creo que este puede ser el error, he probado ver que me devuelve el `done` del `ajax`, y obviamente, me devuelve todo el contenido html que contiene esa página...

Comment: Me devuelve `jquery.min.js:4 POST http://localhost:8888/seoagency/php/editar_cliente.php 500 (Internal Server Error)` @AlbertoSiurob

Comment: mediante que eventos estas mandando el id? nececitamos mas detalles por que en verdad es algo muy facil lo que intentas hacer

Comment: Hola @andygibbs, he editado un poco mi pregunta para que todos podáis entender mejor, y podáis ayudarme, que es lo que necesito. Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Te comento que:

```
$_POST['id']
```

deberías colocarlo antes de la función editarCliente() , claro antes asegurar  con :

```
if (isset($idc)) {
```

como comento alanfcm , el flojo seria si existe esa variable por post : consulta por id y recargo la pagina  , sino flujo normal.. saludos.

Answer (score 0):

te devuelve error por que tienes que poner así al momento de mostrar los datos de la consulta $row['id_cliente'] ya que te falta las comillas simples o dobles $row["id_cliente"]

```
while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    $ec .= '<h2>Editar cliente #'.$row['id_cliente'].'</h2>
            <h3>Datos Personales</h3>

            <input id="idc" type="hidden" value="'.$row['id_cliente'].'">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td class="campoP">Nombre</td>
                    <td class="td"><input id="nombre" type="text" value="'.$row[nombre].'"></td>
                    <td class="td barcode" style="text-align:center" colspan="6" rowspan="2"></td>
                    <td class="campoP">Fecha Registro:</td>
                    <td class="td">' .$row['fecha_registro']. '</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="campoP">Apellidos</td>
                    <td class="td"><input id="apellidos" type="text" value="'.$row['apellidos'].'"></td>
                    <td class="td" colspan="5"></td>
                    <td class="td"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="campoP">Telefono</td>
                    <td class="td"><input id="telefono" type="text" value="'.$row['telefono'].'"></td>
                    <td class="td" colspan="5"></td>
                    <td class="td"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="campoP">Email</td>
                    <td class="td"><input id="email" type="text" value="'.$row['email'].'"></td>
                    <td class="td" colspan="5"></td>
                    <td class="td"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <h3>Datos Comerciales</h3>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td class="campoP" style="width: 10%">Nombre Comercial</td>
                    <td class="td" style="width: 25%"><input id="ncomercial" type="text" value="'.$row['ncomercial'].'"></td>
                    <td class="td" colspan="5"></td>
                    <td class="campoP" style="width: 10%">Nombre Fiscal</td>
                    <td class="td" style="width: 25%"><input id="nfiscal" type="text" value="'.$row['nfiscal'].'"></td>
                    <td class="campoP">NIF/CIF</td>
                    <td class="td"><input id="cif" type="text" value="'.$row['cif'].'"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="campoP">Direccion</td>
                    <td class="td"><input id="direccion" type="text" value="'.$row['direccion'].'"></td>
                    <td class="td" colspan="5"></td>
                    <td class="campoP">Ciudad</td>
                    <td class="td"><input id="ciudad" type="text" value="'.$row['ciudad'].'"></td>
                    <td class="campoP">CP</td>
                    <td class="td"><input id="cp" type="text" value="'.$row['cp'].'"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>';
```